# ReactNativeART documentation and stabillity

Tags: react-native

ReactNativeART examples are available across web (eg. http://browniefed.com/blog/2015/11/07/react-native-how-to-create-twitter-exploding-hearts/) but not in react native docs and source code has references. (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/ART)

Is it available for ios and android and if so why isn't documented yet on react native documentation page?

Answer (score 1):

The ART module has been published and all apis seems to be stable,we have already use it in our project and it preforms well.
Facebook has split react-native and react-dom form react for native and web platform,they share same addons and implements.the ART module is a react-native implement of [react-art](https://github.com/reactjs/react-art),so we have to find documentation in react-art project.While react-art is a library based on [sebmarkbage/art](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/art).this [issue](https://github.com/reactjs/react-art/issues/3) may be helpful.

Comment: I have created a repo called [react-native-art-doc](https://github.com/react-native-china/react-native-ART-doc).check it out!

Comment: Thanks for the effort!